# Get User Information From AD using only USername

Tags: c#-4.0, authentication, active-directory

I have the Following Code

```
    private static string ADValidateUser(string LDAP_URL, string username, string password)
    {
          System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry myDE = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(LDAP_URL, username, password);
        DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(myDE);

        mySearcher.Filter = ("sAMAccountName=" + username);

        try
        {
            SearchResult myresult = mySearcher.FindOne();
            string strName = myresult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["displayname"].Value.ToString();
            string strCompany = myresult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["company"].Value.ToString();
            return ("TRUE|" + (strName + ("|" + strCompany)).ToUpper());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "FALSE|None";
        }
    }
```

I need a modification of this method to get the specified user info without the password but only username .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This would work, but assumes that this process is running as a user that has permissions to access the directory specified in `LDAP_URL`.

Essentially the change is calling the `DirectoryEntry(...)` constructor, and omitting a username and password, which uses the current user.

```
private static string ADValidateUser(string LDAP_URL, string username)
{
      System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry myDE = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(LDAP_URL);
    DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(myDE);

    mySearcher.Filter = ("sAMAccountName=" + username);

    try
    {
        SearchResult myresult = mySearcher.FindOne();
        string strName = myresult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["displayname"].Value.ToString();
        string strCompany = myresult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["company"].Value.ToString();
        return ("TRUE|" + (strName + ("|" + strCompany)).ToUpper());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "FALSE|None";
    }
}
```